# Possible to save query as a variable to be used by other queries (sqlite & python)?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 in my python app and have multiple queries. However, there are certain queries which tend to repeat (e.g 'sum a total quantity of item X in inventory'). Is there any way I can save such query and use it in other queries?

Example of my sum query, say we will name it `QuantityInInventory(x)`

```
SELECT SUM(have)
    FROM inventory
    WHERE ID = x
    GROUP BY ID
```

Example of other, simple, query which would use `QuantityInInventory(x)`

```
SELECT ID
    FROM items
    WHERE QuantityInInventory(ID) > 5
```

Any way to do this? I know these 2 queries can be merged into a nested query (or HAVE query), but that's not the point.

EDIT:
A method using this query would look like (in a sqlite3.Connection inherited class, note that I didn't sanitise inputs or checked if queries actually returned non-None values, this is just an example):

```
def getQuantityInInventoryFromID(self, ID):
    return self.execute("QuantityInInventory(?)", (ID,)).fetchone()[0]

def getItemsWithInventoryHigherThan(self, itemId, quantity):

    query = """
        SELECT ID
            FROM items
            WHERE QuantityInInventory({0}) > {1}""".format(itemId, quantity)

    return self.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Comment: Do you want to save the *result* of the query? Or the *string* of the query itself so that it can be put in other queries?

Comment: I want to save the query itself, so that it can be used in other queries - so neither the result, nor the string. I don't want to create a function/method to request `QuantityInInventory` for a specific ID by my python code. I want to use `QuantityInInventory` by my other queries. Of course, if I were to create a func/method for it, it should be something along: edited OP.

Comment: The closest thing to what you're asking is a view.